# App compat actionbar v21 app icon is not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, material-design

I upgraded to avtionbar app compat v21 for material design purpose.

But I observed that its not showing the app icon in actionbar and navigation menu and back button is taking more space compare to old appcompat libs.

Have any one faced this issue? I searched a lot but did not found anything useful.

Below line is also not working.

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

I am using style for actionbar which is like

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_action_bar</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>
</style>
```

I am aware of other solution like Toolbar. But I am in middle of release and due to time constraint I am looking for some quick solution if available. Adding a Toolbar will require more time.

Comment: Seems that it is actually removed from the internal implementation itself. Many revamped Google apps have no icon in action bar. Using Toolbar can do the trick. :)

Answer (score 5):

`setIcon/setLogo` method will only work if you have set **DisplayOptions** Try this -

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

You can also set options for displaying LOGO(just add constant `ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO`). More information - [displayOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayOptions(int,%20int))

Answer (score 4):

I added this to my theme:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
```

and then the ActionBar was back.

Note: if you use supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); then you can't just do that, but will have to add the Toolbar to your layout (which isnt that much work, anyway)

Comment: Thanks, will try this for sure and let u know

Answer (score 0):

Use getSupportActionbar instead of actionbar

```
Actionbar actionbar = getSupportActionBar()
actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionbar.setIcon(YOUR ICON);
```