# App icon is not visible on Actionbar in android Lollipop and above

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I just migrate from api 19 Kitkat to api 21 Lollipop. And now I have found that the app icon is not there on actionbar. I feel that my app looks kind of different. So is there any way to show the app icon.

Comment: Try this - [ActionBar - Display Options][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966854/app-compat-actionbar-v21-app-icon-is-not-showing/27442133#27442133

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the Material theme (and AppCompat version 21 which is based on it), the Action Bar follows the [material design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) and uses a [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

> - *A title and subtitle.* The title should be a signpost for the Toolbar's current position in the navigation hierarchy and the content contained there. The subtitle, if present should indicate any extended information about the current content. **If an app uses a logo image it should strongly consider omitting a title and subtitle.**
>
> In modern Android UIs developers should lean more on a visually distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. **The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.**

However, if you want an application icon, [setLogo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#setLogo(int)) is the correct method.

Comment: how and where to use setlogo() method?

Comment: You can call it on your `getSupportActionBar()` in `onCreate()` if you'd like

Answer (score 6):

I would also like to show my awesome app icon in Lollipop+, so here's what I used.

```
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setIcon(Drawable); // Or drawable resource id.
```

Source: [ActionBar#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean))

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me -

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Subtitle");
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | 
ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO); // Customize if you need to

getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.iconhere); // or setLogo
```

It is important that you **setDisplayOptions** as setIcon/setLogo doesn't seem to be working without it. Original answer - [App compat actionbar v21 app icon is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966854/app-compat-actionbar-v21-app-icon-is-not-showing/27442133#27442133)

This code worked on my device. Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Been searching for a solution for the whole morning. This one works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it:

```
package com.your.package;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
    }
}
```

Which will give you this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you have to used toolbar in your app like below.

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

**v21\styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>

        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navigationBarColor</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

in your layout use toolbar like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/windowBackground">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">


        </FrameLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

in your Java file write below code for set icon:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        if (toolbar != null) {

            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.icn_menu);
            //toolbar.setTitle("Title");
            setTitle("Title");
            //toolbar.setSubtitle("Subtitle");
            //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
getSupportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I tried that but it shows a back arrow icon, I need the app icon.

Comment: this can help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525229/toolbar-navigation-icon-never-set)