# Where I paste the following thread solved code ic_launcher?

Tags: android

In that part of my archive in android paste the following code solved in the thread =>

[App icon is not visible on Actionbar in android lolipop and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539627/actionbar-home-app-icon-is-not-visible-in-android-lolipop)

I´m new in Android.

But I have the following code

```
package com.example.cursoandroid.holamundo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

I´ve import android.app.actionBar, if I´ve ActionBarActivity.
But ActionBarActivity haven´t any method: ActionBarActivity.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

---

I realize the following change. But the inc_launcher don´t appear

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: onCreate of your Activity

Comment: paste this code in your `onCreate()`: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

Comment: I realize the following change but the ic_launcher don´t appear  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }