# How to add an icon to the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-theme

I am trying to add an icon to my ActionBar for the whole Appliction.

I reference the CustomActionBarTheme in my Appication Tag in the manifest.

My ActionBars are turning Blue but there is no Icon.

Anybody have any ideas why?

Thanks

[Duplicate]
[show icon in actionbar/toolbar with AppCompat-v7 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440279/show-icon-in-actionbar-toolbar-with-appcompat-v7-21)

```
<application
        android:name=".NfcScannerApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
        android:debuggable = "true" >
```

.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/cf_blue</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/cf_blue</item>
        <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440279/show-icon-in-actionbar-toolbar-with-appcompat-v7-21 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966854/app-compat-actionbar-v21-app-icon-is-not-showing etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks again Mark, worked a treat. create an answer if you like.

Comment: I suggest you pick whichever one of those that you like and mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @CommonsWare When custom action bar is used, then it compulsory use both <item> tags one for current version and another for support library. like  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item> and <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set app icon in action bar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908011/how-to-set-app-icon-in-action-bar-in-android)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show icon in actionbar/toolbar with AppCompat-v7 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440279/show-icon-in-actionbar-toolbar-with-appcompat-v7-21)

Answer (score 1):

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
```

Comment: no need documentation, **this is working very well**

Comment: Not working for me. It not displaying my icon.

Answer (score -1):

```
ActionBar ab=getActionBar();
ab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
```

Comment: could you add some more information around your answer?

Comment: I am using the support library so i have tried ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
  actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); but it doesn'y work