# how to set app icon in action bar in android

Tags: android

i want set my app icon on my action bar please help me

I have tried this  but nothing created:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MukilFM");
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.fm);
```

Comment: Must be sure that  `appCompact-v7` dependency in your `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a separate layout.xml file for action bar and include it as a custom action bar in main.xml and set the main activity's theme to noTitle bar.
 **Here is my custome_app_bar.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:padding="5dp"
>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/acton_bar_imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

and including in the main.xml is like that ....

```
    <include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/custome_app_bar"
    />
```

Comment: ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); it shows error in this

Comment: dont need to access it programmatically ... why you are using  **ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);**

Comment: - just create a separate xml file and include it in activity.xml

Comment: its wrking but it affect my views inside my layout

Comment: im using Actionbar Activity if i disable Action bar it also affecting my views

Comment: ooo i c.... it needs full code and xml .. review ...  just try to do this for activity **public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity**

Answer (score 0):

Use `setLogo()` method.

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.fm);
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.apple.mukilapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:105)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions()
        | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.adnace_search_i);
ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
                | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
layoutParams.rightMargin = 40;
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
actionBar.setCustomView(imageView);
```

Comment: in this ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM showing me error

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.fm);
```

And one more thing if you are using `Activity` then change to `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (ab != null) {
            ab.setLogo(R.drawable.fm);
            ab.setTitle("MukilFM");
            ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.whiteic);
```